# Is calling x = std::array<T, N> () same as declaring std::array<T, N> x?

Tags: c++, stdarray

I am writing custom move constructor and move assignment operator for `class_name`. I would like to know if calling `std::array` as `std::array<T, N> ()` is correct or not.

```cpp
class_name::class_name(class_name&& other) :
    mem_A(std::exchange(other.memA, class_memA())),
    arr_memB(std::exchange(other.arr_memB, std::array<T,N> ()))
{
}
    
class_name& class_name::operator=(class_name&& other)
{
   if (this != other)
   {
      mem_A = mem_A(std::exchange(other.memA, class_memA()));                                                   
      arr_memB = arr_memB(std::exchange(other.arr_memB, std::array<T,N> ()));     
      func_clear();                    
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: what has the title to do with the body of the question?

Comment: The best way to write a move constructor is `class_name::class_name(class_name&& other) = default;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver ideally yes, but if the class contains raw pointers then the default move constructor won't move them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your use of `array` is fine, provided that is how `arr_memB` is declared to begin with. You could use `decltype` instead to avoid guessing.

But you do need to remove the redundant member name references when calling `exchange()` in the move assignment operator. Calling a member's constructor by its name works only in a constructor's member initialization list.

Try this:

```cpp
class_name& class_name::operator=(class_name&& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        mem_A = std::exchange(other.memA, class_memA());
        arr_memB = std::exchange(other.arr_memB, std::array<T,N>());
        func_clear();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
class_name::class_name(class_name&& other) :
    mem_A(std::exchange(other.memA, decltype(mem_A){})),
    arr_memB(std::exchange(other.arr_memB, decltype(arr_memB){}))
{
} 

class_name& class_name::operator=(class_name&& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        mem_A = std::exchange(other.memA, decltype(mem_A){});
        arr_memB = std::exchange(other.arr_memB, decltype(arr_memB){});
        func_clear();
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This still seems like a bad design. It needlessly creates `class_memA()` and `std::array<T,N>`, just to leave `other` in a default-initialized state. But a move operator can leave the source object in _any_ state. `std::swap(mem_A, other->mem_A)` is just fine. And that even saves the `this != &other` check; `std::swap(a,a)` is safe.

Comment: @MSalters a move operation can't leave `other` in just *any* state, it must leave it in an *unspecified **but valid** state*. As for swapping vs exchanging, that is more a matter of personal choice. Certainly, swapping *works*, but for instance, I don't like swapping the existing state unless I **know** `other` is being destroyed immediately afterwards, but that is not guaranteed in this example, so it is OK to not want to leak private data to the caller. Nothing wrong with exchanging a default state instead. Both ways work.

Comment: We already have the precondition that `*this` is in a valid state. So that's not a concern. As for "`other` being destroyed, that's not really your problem, is it? The `private` data still remains `private` in `other`, since that has the same type. True, it works, but it forgoes the efficiency which justifies a move. Just use copy assignment where efficiency is irrelevant.

Comment: @MSalters in `class name c1, c2; ... c1 = std::move(c2);`, `c2` is not destroyed, after the move, so swapping `c1`'s old data into `c2` could leak information, whether `private` or otherwise (and there are ways to access `private` data). It makes sense to reset `c2` into a default state if possible rather than a swapped state in this example. But like I said, it is a personal choice what state you decide to leave a moved-from object.